# WPF MVVM Single ViewModel for Display and Editing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am using the example from [Josh Smith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). He has a WorkspaceViewModel which display a list of CustomerViewModels. He is using the same ViewModel for displaying all Customers and for editing one single customer.

Is this a good practice? If I have a list of CustomerViewModels I dont need the SaveCommand or the CloseCommand or some IsSelected Flag.

Is it better to have a seperate EditCustomerViewModel? But how to deal with Workspace related stuff? For example:

```
public class Workspace : ViewModel
{
    public ICommand CloseCommand;
}

public class AllCustomers : Workspace
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> CustomerViewModels;
}

// Option A (one ViewModel for display and edit):
public class CustomerViewModel : ? 
{
    public string CustomerName;
    public ICommand SaveCommand;    
}
```

Or seperation:

```
// Option B:
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModel 
{
    public string CustomerName;
}

public class EditCustomerViewModel : Workspace
{
    public CustomerViewModel CustomerViewModel;
    public ICommand SaveCommand;
}

// Option C (CustomerViewModel does not need CloseCommand but EditCustomerViewModel does):
public class CustomerViewModel : Workspace 
{
    public string CustomerName;
}

public class EditCustomerViewModel : CustomerViewModel
{   
    public ICommand SaveCommand;    
}
```

**Edit:**
I try to clarify my problem. In the CustomerViewModel in the example of Josh Smith, he has Commands for closing and saving a customer. In the AllCustomerView he has a GridView that binds to a ObservableCollection of CustomerViewModels. But in the GridView the both commands are not necessary. In the GridView I can ignore both commands, but is that a good design?

Comment: from your options a is the one to choose , in option b costumer is a model and not a viewmodel and in c its by inheritance, you need to divide the viewmodels by views.

Comment: If it's Josh Smith, then yes, it's a "good practice".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean as a quick look at that article shows that he is using both a list and a view/edit view modal called `AllCustomers­ViewModel` and `CustomerViewModel` respectively. Which would certainly be the recommended practise rather than using a single view model which has more than one responsibility.

Both of these view models inherit from `WorkspaceViewModel` which adds his workspace functionality. So, in summary, I would follow his pattern if you want to build something similar. You should also seriously consider an MVVM framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) which adds easy convention based view composition as well as screen life cycle.